# Search for a key in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

"trip" is a list of dictionaries.  In this instance, the key "trip_block" only appears in the 6th dictionary.  Why doesn't this work:

```
trip[:]['trip_block']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

But this does work and returns the value:

```
trip[5]['trip_block']
```

Since that key appears in different indexes, I would really like to search for it by using trip[:].  I'm trying to use this in an if statement:

```
if trip[:]['trip_block']:
```

Comment: What do you mean by "why doesn't this work"? Do you know what ``trip[:]`` means? What do you expect the output of ``trip[:]['trip_block']`` to be? Are you looking for *why* the ``[:]`` variant doesn't work, or for what to use *instead*?

Comment: "why doesn't this work" isn't a very good question here or anywhere else. `trip[:]` is a whole lot of indices while `trip[5]` is a single index. You are trying to tell python "FIND THIS KEY IN EVERYTHING" but python doesn't do that without you telling it how.

Comment: "You are trying to tell python "FIND THIS KEY IN EVERYTHING" That's exactly what I'm trying to do. Why wouldn't it search through all the dictionaries until it finds a key of "trip_block"?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to loop through your list. The `[:]` variant just grabs all of the dictionaries in the list. Take a look at this and see if it will work for you:

```
for dictionary in trip: #loop through list of dicts
    if 'trip_block' in dictionary.keys(): #check if key is in this dict
        print(dictionary['trip_block'])
        break #end loop, don't use break if there's more than one dict with this key and you need them all
```

Comment: I didn't think about that, I was trying to access the value through the list, then the dict, instead of just using the loop to access the dictionary. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

`trip[:]` is a list. Trying to index it like a dictionary isn't going to work. If you want a list of all the values that dictionaries that contain 'trip_block' try:

```py
[d['trip_block'] for d in trip if 'trip_block' in d]
```

Answer (score 0):

the `[:]` is a slicing, and what it does depends on the type of trip. If trip is a list, this line will create a shallow copy of the list. For an object of type tuple or a str, it will do nothing (the line will do the same without [:]), and for a (say) NumPy array, it will create a new view to the same data.

You could use the following instead:

```
trip = [
{"name": "name1", "trip_block__": 10},
{"name": "name2", "trip_block_": 5},
{"name": "name3", "trip_block": 7}
]


res1 = next(item for item in trip if 'trip_block' in item.keys())
print(res1)


res2 = list(filter(lambda trip_block: 'trip_block' in trip_block.keys(), trip))
print(res2)
```

The first method is finding the `dict` that has the desired key.

The second one the filter the `dict` that consist the desired key

Comment: You obviously know about comprehensions, since you use them (actually a generator expression) in the first case. Why use ``list``+``filter``+``lambda`` instead of a list comprehension in the second case?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The `list` is because `filter` returns a filter object. the `labmda` is just in the case the asker will what to implement something with a little more logic. The question is not so clear and I decided to post both options

Comment: I know why you need all three of ``list``+``filter``+``lambda`` once you chose one of them. I'm asking why you are not using/recommending a single list comprehension instead.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I got your point, you are correct. I used the logic of list comprehension in the first case and in the second is just extra I guess, but I would probably go with the list comprehension alone

Answer (score 0):

trip[:] means you get just a copy of the whole list

You need to iterate over the list...

and because it appears in different indexes you need to store it again in an list.

You can use list comprehension like

```
trip_block_items = [item["trip_block"] for item in trip if "trip_block" in item]
```

or a simply a for loop

```
trip_block_items = []

for item in trip:
    if "trip_block" in item:
        trip_block_items.append(item["trip_block"])
```